# Filling report label with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a sub routine that builds retrieves data to fill in a calendar report.  The routine works fine; however, the part of the code that sets the title of the report in the report header does not work. The routine runs without error but the label is empty.

Currently, the retrieves the year from a input form but I do think this is the issue because even if type "2018 Safety Calendar" it still returns nothing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```vb
Public Sub loadReportYearCalendar(theReport As Report)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim datStart As Date
    Dim rptControl As Report
    Dim rptYear As String

    m_strCTLLabel = "labelCELL"
    m_strCTLLabelHeader = "labelDAY"
    rptYear = Forms![fr_SafetyCal]![txtYear]

    'Load calendar data for the specified year into the collection
    Call getCalendarData

    With theReport
        'Get the first month of the specified year
        datStart = "1/1/" & Forms![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear]
        'Add the specified year to the report's label
        .Controls("labelCalendarHeaderLine2").Value = rptYear & " Safety Calender"
        For i = 1 To 12
            'Set pointer to subreport control hosting the mini-calendar
            Set rptControl = .Controls("childCalendarMonth" & i).Report
            'Run procedure to populate control with it's respective year
            Call loadReportCalendar(rptControl, datStart)
            'Reset and obtain first day of the following month
            datStart = DateAdd("m", 1, datStart)
        Next i

    End With
    'Clean up
    Set colCalendarDates = Nothing
    Set rptControl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint, step through your code, watch was happens

Comment: You may have to change `labelCalendarHeaderLine2` to a textbox. Labels may require a repaint to display a new Caption. Also, though it may not matter here, don't set a date from a string. Use `= DateSerial(Forms![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear], 1, 1)`.

Comment: I made some edits based on the suggestions; however, it still does not display the year.

Comment: How do you call this sub (from which report event)? -- Which report view do you open (report or print preview)?

Comment: The sub is called from a module when the report is opened.  I have uploaded a working file with the necessary elements so you can see how the project is laid out.  Open the pop up form fr_SafetyCal select a year and click open.  You'll note the Year does not display in the textbox in the header of the report.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S81_T9Z6X_xIKDvAehEKwXArakSKoZzc/view?usp=sharing